# Partial code coverage of await

Tags: c#, nunit, async-await, code-coverage

I have the following code in my solution :-

```
public async void ExecuteScan(string barcode)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcode))
    {
        barcode = await _scannerService.Scan();
    }

    ConsignmentReferenceCode = barcode;
}
```

I have tests that seem to cover this method however I can't seem to get 100% code coverage. The following line is highlighted as being partially covered :-

```
barcode = await _scannerService.Scan();
```

How might I address this to achieve 100% code coverage?

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603813/code-coverage-for-async-methods